# Display bug on badges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

On https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=3043, I see:

[image]

The "Awarded 248340 times" probably should be elsewhere.

Also, the `userid` GET parameter should make the system show how many times the specific user got that badge, and when.

Chrome on XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now, once deployed.